# EF4 CTP5 - Map foreign key without object references?

Tags: entity-framework-4, mapping, foreign-keys, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I feel like this should have a simple answer, but I can't find it.

I have 2 POCOs:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that there are no object references on either POCO.  With Code-First, how do I make EF4 CTP5 define a relationship between the two database tables?

(I know this is an unusual scenario, but I am exploring what's possible and what's not with Code-First)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. As you can see below, all of the fluent API methods for setting up associations require specifying the `Navigation Property` as their parameter.

```
HasMany<TTargetEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, ICollection<TTargetEntity>>> navigationPropertyExpression) 

HasOptional<TTargetEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, TTargetEntity>> navigationPropertyExpression) 

HasRequired<TTargetEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, TTargetEntity>> navigationPropertyExpression)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought as much.

Comment: Actually, do you think it would have been possible if I weren't using Code-First and I hacked the csdl/msl/ssdl files?

Comment: I don't think so but I'm not sure, you can give it a try though.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you don't want to use object references?  It looks very elegant to use them:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And you can still access the Category Id via your product as `product.Category.Id`.

Comment: As stated, I am exploring what's possible and what's not with Code-First.